# For someone to do something vs so that

Tags: difference, phrases, to-infinitive

I was wondering, if there is any difference between "for someone to do" and "so that".
For instance, Is
"many parents used to beat their children for them to study" the same as "many parents used to beat their children so that they study"??
In my opinion, if you say "for them to study", it sounds more like you are helping them study, while "so that" version implies you just want your children to study.. But as a non native speaker, I am not so certain. Please leave any opinion! I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: "beat their children for them to study" and "beat their children so that they study" are both incorrect grammar. The first sentence is not salvageable. The second sentence is corrected by adding a verb: "beat their children so that they *would* study."

Comment: thank you for your comment! What about "Beat their children to study"??